Show that the series of the reciprocal of $a_n$ converging means the series of the reciprocal of the cesaro sums of $a_n$ converges
Title is long and hard but, if $a_n$ is some real, strictly positive sequence, define: $$b_n = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n a_k $$ And suppose $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{a_n} < \infty$, show that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{b_n} < \infty$.
This is a problem from a Virginia tech math competition in 1999. I have no idea how to do this, but my general idea was to use AM-HM inverted to get$$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{b_n} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n}{a_1 + \ldots + a_n} \leq  \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\frac{1}{a_1} + \ldots + \frac{1}{a_n}}{n} $$ I know that since $\frac{1}{a_n} \to 0$ then the cesaro sum also goes to $0$, meaning the upper bound can converge, and I believe it should. But I am not sure how to show that this converges using the fact that the sequence of $\frac{1}{a_n}$ converges as well, since $\frac{1}{n}$ does not converge.

This bound is not sharp enough to conclude. For example, take $a_n = n^2$. Then $\sum 1/a_n$ converges. We have $b_n = \Theta(n^2)$, so $\sum 1/b_n$ also converges. But $\sum (1/a_1 + ... + 1/a_n)/n \geq \sum 1/n$ diverges.

By Cauchy-Schwarz we have
$$(\sum_{ i = 1}^{n}a_i)\cdot (\sum_{ i = 1}^{n}\frac{i^4}{a_i})\geq \left(\sum_{i = 1}^{n}i^2\right)^2$$
$$\frac{1}{\sum_{ i = 1}^{n}a_i}\leq \frac{\sum \limits_{ i = 1}^{n}\frac{i^4}{a_i}}{\left(\sum \limits_{i = 1}^{n}i^2\right)^2} = \frac{\sum \limits_{ i = 1}^{n}\frac{i^4}{a_i}}{\left(\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}\right)^2}$$
$$\frac{1}{b_n}= \frac{n}{\sum_{ i = 1}^{n}a_i}\leq \frac{\sum \limits_{ i = 1}^{n}\frac{i^4}{a_i}}{\frac{n(n+1)^2(2n+1)^2}{36}}$$
and (I'll technically be doing the summation converge proof in reverse) we can see that
$$\sum_{ i =1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{b_i} \leq  \sum_{ i =1}^{\infty}\frac{\sum \limits_{ j = 1}^{i}\frac{j^4}{a_j}}{\frac{i(i+1)^2(2i+1)^2}{36}} = \sum_{j = 1}^{\infty} \frac{j^4}{a_j}\sum_{ i =j}^{\infty} \frac{36}{i(i+1)^2(2i+1)^2}$$
$$\leq  \sum_{j = 1}^{\infty} \frac{j^4}{a_j}\sum_{ i =j}^{\infty} \frac{9}{i^5}$$
Finally, note that there is a fixed constant $C$ such that $j^4\sum_{ i =j}^{\infty} \frac{9}{i^5}\leq C$ for all $j\geq 1$; just use integral bounding. Thus convergence is shown.
